# Why doesn’t Gauss’ theorem of electrostatics depend upon the size of the area?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

When I was studying electric flux I found that the electric flux depends upon the area through which the electric field line passes. The more the area, the more the electric flux will be.

But in Gauss's Law, I found that it doesn't matter whether I take a big sphere enclosing the charge $q$ or a small sphere including the same charge; the electric flux passing through it will remain the same.

How is this possible that electric flux depends upon the area, as we study in its definition, but Gauss’ theorem says it doesn't matter whether the size is big or small… the flux will remain the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric field is not constant around an electric charge; the field lines radiate outward from the charge, converging to a point at the charge they originate from. Think of the electric flux as (proportional to) the number of field lines going through an area. Then a sphere enclosing the charge will always have the same number of field lines going through it, that is, it will always have the same total flux.

(I should mention that the 'number' of electric field lines is really infinite, but in pictures one generally only draws a representative amount of them to get the idea of what the field looks like.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you don't have all the (advanced) mathematical tools for really appreciate the topics, so I'll split my answer in two paragraph, the first with a qualitative description, the latter with a more detailed description using mathematical tools.

### Brief qualitative answer

The flux is the same across the two spherical surfaces, because the surface of a sphere increases with $r^2$, while the intensity of the electric field decreases with $r^{-2}$, so that these two contributions compensate eachother to give a constant flux.

### Some mathematical details

Let's imagine the electric field produced by a point charge $q$, and put the origin of the coordinates, s.t. $\mathbf{x_0} = \mathbf{0}$. In every point $\mathbf{x}$ in space, the electric field has

- radial direction, i.e. is parallel to the vector $\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x_0} = \mathbf{x}$;
- intensity decreasing with the inverse of the square of the distance, i.e. $|\mathbf{e}(\mathbf{r})| \propto \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x_0}|^2}  =: \frac{1}{r^2}$

so that it can be written as
$\mathbf{e}(\mathbf{r}) =\dfrac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon} \dfrac{1}{r^2} \mathbf{\hat{r}}$.

On the other hand, the area of a spherical surface increases with the square of its radius $r$. This surface has unit normal vector pointing in the radial direction $\mathbf{\hat{n}} = \mathbf{\hat{r}}$.

Thus when you evaluate the flux of the electric field across a spherical surface $\mathscr{S} $ with center in $\mathbf{x_0}$, you can evaluate the integral using the definition of solid angle $dS = r^2 d\Omega$, with full solid angle equal to $4\pi$

$\Phi_{\mathscr{S}}(\mathbf{e}) = \displaystyle \oint_{\mathscr{S}} \mathbf{e} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \, dS = \displaystyle \oint_{\Omega} \dfrac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon} \dfrac{1}{r^2} \underbrace{\mathbf{\hat{r}} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{r}}}_{=1} r^2 d\Omega = \displaystyle \oint_{\Omega} \dfrac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon} d\Omega = \dfrac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon} \cdot 4\pi = \dfrac{q}{\epsilon}$.

You can easily see that the intensity of the flux is not a function of the radius of the sphere.

### Observation

Do not talk about the number of field lines, since they are defined as the geometric lines tangent to the vector field at each point in space, and you can define as many field lines as you want since the space is continuous and you can get an infinite number of infinitely close points and defining an infinite number of field lines passing through them.